# Converting Guid to Cassandra UUID

Tags: cassandra, fluentcassandra

I want to convert a Guid to a UUID or a string version of the same so that the following CQL query will work.

```
                        if (cassandraDb.ExecuteQuery(string.Format("SELECT OrderGroupId FROM Order WHERE OrderGroupId={0}", orderGroupId)).Count() <= 0)                            {
```

The variable 'orderGroupId' is a Guid. Obviously this is using FluentCassandra in a C#/.NET environmnet. Any hints?

Thank you.

Comment: Or how would I change this query so that rather than executing a CQL statement I perform an equivalent 'test' for a UUID value in the Cassandra database using FluentCassandra?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you already have a UUID data (FluentCassandra.Types.UUIDType or FluentCassandra.Types.TimeUUIDType) and you want to compare it to something else?

Answer (score 0):

To convert System.Guid to FluentCassandra.Types.UUIDType you just need to assign one into the other.

Same goes for FluentCassandra.Types.TimeUUIDType.

Comment: But for this query it needs to be explicitly converted to a form that can be inserted in the string CQL query.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand the comment. Do you want to know how to insert a GUID value as a string to a CQL SELECT query?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the CQL query directly as a string by using the **.ToString()** property.

```
string.Format("SELECT OrderGroupId FROM Order WHERE OrderGroupId={0}", orderGroupId.ToString())
```

Should work fine. If it does not... you may want to try this (which I found on a comment thread on one of the C# clients):

```
    protected static string ToCqlString(Guid guid) {
        var bytes = guid.ToByteArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10) {
                sb.Append("-");
            }
            var b = bytes[i];
            sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);

        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Cheers,
Allison